# Agregar evento onclick a elementos html dinamicamente con javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

Tengo una galeria de imagenes (aprox 100 imagenes) y a cada una necesito agregarle un onclick="function()", en otras palabras necesito un script que agregue el onclick="function()" a cada etiqueta  por mi, y asi no tener teclear ese onlclik a cada etiqueta. he intentado de estas 2 formas.

```javascript
let IMGs = Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('img'));
IMGs.map((img) => img.setAttribute(onclick,'openFullImg(this.src)'));


document.getElementsByName('img').addEventListener('click', openFullImg(this.src));
```

Comment: Y por qué no se lo agregas al elemento padre? Creo que los eventos se heredaban.

Comment: lo mejor seria delegar el evento al documento y chequear que si el que disparo el evento es una imagen actuar en consecuencia

Comment: mhmhm.. no lo habia pensado, voy a probarlo, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como ya te han indicado correctamente en los comentarios, una posible solución pasa por utilizar la **delegación de eventos**, asignando ese evento a un elemento padre, lo más cercano posible, que los contenga a todos. Eso sería lo más óptimo. O bien asignarlos al elemento *body* o *document*, que no sería tan óptimo pero también funcionaría.

Usando el *body*, podría ser así:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if(event.target.tagName == "IMG") {
     openFullImg(event.target.src)
  }
});
```

donde **event.target** representa el elemento que ha recibido el evento y
donde **event.target.tagName** nos devuelve el tag del elemento que ha recibido el evento, y mediante el condicional nos aseguramos que sea **IMG** para entrar en él y ejecutar la función **openFullImg()**.

Snippet de muestra:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName == "IMG") {
    openFullImg(event.target.src)
  }
});

function openFullImg(src) {
  console.log(src)
}
```

```html
<img src="imagen1.jpg" alt="imagen1">
<img src="imagen2.jpg" alt="imagen2">
```

Usando un elemento que contenga las imágenes referenciado por su **id** podría ser así:

```
<div id="imagenes">
  <img src="imagen1" alt="imagen1">
  <img src="imagen2" alt="imagen2">
</div>
<script>
contenedor = document.getElementById("imagenes")
contenedor.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName == "IMG") {
    openFullImg(event.target.src)
  }
});
</script>
```

Snippet de muestra:

```js
contenedor = document.getElementById("imagenes")
contenedor.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName == "IMG") {
    openFullImg(event.target.src)
  }
});

function openFullImg(src) {
  console.log(src)
}
```

```html
<div id="imagenes">
  <img src="imagen1" alt="imagen1">
  <img src="imagen2" alt="imagen2">
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte masterguru, fue de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Con un 'for' puedes recorrer todos los tag 'img'

```
  <div class="col">
      <img src="https://www.jquery-az.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/2.1-HTML-img-src.jpg" alt="baner-imagen">   
  </div>
  <div class="col">
      <img src="https://html.com/wp-content/plugins/htmlcodetutorial-plugin/assets/images/chrome-true.png" alt="baner-imagen">   
  </div>
  <div class="col">
      <img src="https://html.com/wp-content/plugins/htmlcodetutorial-plugin/assets/images/firefox-true.png" alt="baner-imagen">   
  </div>
```

```
 <script>
    var imagenes = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i=0; i<imagenes.length; i++)
    {          
      imagenes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('click')
      });
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: gracias Frnk, sirvio el bucle(añadio correctamente la función a todas las etiquetas img) pero con un cierto inconveniente, al cargar la pagina por defecto me abre el contenedor de la imagen. sin haber clickeado en ninguna etiqueta, al cerrar ese contenedor si funciona correctamente todo. Se agradece el aporte.